# What's the meaning of "Include Directories" and "Include Headers" in Netbeans for C++?

Tags: c++, netbeans, ide

In Netbeans **8.0** for C++ there is an option in Project Properties->Build->C++ Compiles for 
"Include Directories" and "Include Headers".

[image]

What is the difference between them?

Comment: "Include directories" designates where to search for included files given with the `#include "file"` preprocessor directive. "Include Headers" might refer to particular header files to include with generated code from your IDE.

Comment: What version are you using? I'm on 7.2.1 and I've only got the `Include Directories` option, which as @πάνταῥεῖ said is where the compiler tool chain will search for `#include` headers in your code.

Comment: @txtechhelp I've updated the question with the information you want.